# Regular expression to get variables from a razor file (c#)

Tags: c#, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that gets all the variables from a Razor file.

Here's an example

```
<p>Hello @Model.Name,</p>
<p>@Model.Text</p>
<a href="/@Model.Slug">Visit our site</a>
```

I would like a regex that gets all "words" starting with @Model.

In this case that would be @Model.Name, @Model.Text and @Model.Slug

This is what I've come up so far

```
"\B@Model.(\w|.)+\b"
```

But I can't get the variable inside the `p` tag properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\B@Model(?:\.\w+)+
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CB%40Model%28%3F%3A%5C.%5Cw%2B%29%2B&i=%3Cp%3EHello%20%40Model.Name%2C%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Cp%3E%40Model.Text%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3Ca%20href%3D%22%2F%40Model.Slug%22%3EVisit%20our%20site%3C%2Fa%3E)

C#:

```
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"\B@Model(?:\.\w+)+")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Value)
    .ToList();
```

**Details**

- `\B` - non-word boundary
- `@Model` - literal text
- `(?:\.\w+)+` - 1+ occurrences of `.` followed with 1+ word chars (letters, digits, some diacritics and connector punctuation).

Note that in case there can be non-word chars, you will need to replace `\w` with a character class like `[\w-]`, this will match word chars and hyphens.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest `@Model\.\w+`

Explanation:

`@Model` - match literally `@Model`

`\.` - match `.` literally

`\w+` - match one or more of word characters

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JwS5xu/1)